# Adding a condition

Tags: python

I am having difficulty adding a condition to my function.

I want to write a function with two parameters where an `input` box asks to enter a letter they want to replace and the function replaces that letter, chosen in the `input`, with the second parameter, `letter`, in the function. For example,

> replace(“I love to code”, “p”)
>
> “Enter a letter you would like to replace”: o
>
> I lpve tp cpde

So far so good.

```
def replace(phrase,letter): 
   c = input("Enter a letter you would like to replace")
   d = ""    
   for char in phrase:
    if char == c:
        d += letter       
    else:
        d += char        
   print(d)
```

But I want to add a condition, which I am having difficulty doing. If the letter entered in the input is not in the first parameter `phrase` then it should print out "letter must be in phrase". And asks again to enter a letter they like to replace that is in the phrase given in parameter `phrase`.

Also, I only want to use enumeration. I do not wish to use any build in functions like append or replace.

Comment: *Please* use meaningful variable names.  That code should take about 5 seconds tops to read in its entirety; instead my brain has to backtrack three times and subsequently give up because it's not worth it.

Comment: @roippi lol, I am sorry. I wont make that mistake next time.

Comment: Why did I receive downvotes?

Comment: Because the question is of very low quality. That's common language constructs, thus it shows you didn't even bother to learn the basics.

Comment: Being formatted with haphazard indents, nonsensical variable names, and no attempt to solve the problem or describe where you got stuck, just "I want to do this", doesn't help either.

Comment: @abarnert there was an attempt to solve, I posted my code. And I did describe where I got stuck. And I never said, "I want to do this".

Comment: You never said "I want to do this"? It's the start of three of your four paragraphs! And meanwhile, you haven't posted any code that's an attempt to solve your problem, or explained what part you're having trouble with. Where's the code that tries to check whether the letter is in the input phrase, print out an error message, or ask again? Which one of those things do you not know how to do? Can you see why this makes it look like you're just asking someone to write code to your spec?

Comment: @abarnert That was never my intention. I just didnt know how to apply the condition correctly because everything I tried didn't work.

Comment: @Robben: "Everything I tried didn't work" is not something that anyone can debug. Show us what you tried and what didn't work about it and why you couldn't fix it. You asked why you got a downvote, you got plenty of comments explaining, you haven't fixed anything anyone has raised, and now you have 4 downvotes instead of 1—and, more importantly, your question still apparently doesn't have an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean that is false by default, and set it to true if the letter `char` is found.

If the boolean is still false after all the characters are processed, spit out an error,

```
def replace(a,b): 
while True:
    c = input("Enter a letter you would like to replace") 
    d = "" 
    charfound = False
    for char in a: 
        if char == c: 
            charfound = True    
            d += b 
        else: 
            d+= char 
    if charfound:
        print(d)
        break
    else:
        print('Letter must be in phrase!')
```

If you want the script to re-ask the user if the character isn't found, you need to place all the code in a forever-loop (i.e `while True:`) and break it on a *successful* execution

Answer (score 0):

To check if a character `'x'` is in a string `my_string`, you can use the `in` operator:

```
>>> my_string = 'I love to code'
>>> 'o' in my_string
True
>>> 't' in my_string
True
>>> 'p' in my_string
False
```

Of course, you can also store that character in a variable:

```
>>> a = 'p'
>>> a in my_string
False
>>> a = 'o'
>>> a in my_string
True
```

Comment: But my question was how to add a condition where if the input letter given is not in the phrase then it should print out "letter must be in phrase". And redirects another input screen asking to enter a letter they would like to replace.

Comment: `a in my_string` *is* a condition. You can use that just like you used the condition `char == c` in your code. And to repeat something, you use a loop. So you want to repeat asking the user for new input as long as the condition is not fulfilled.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `raw_input()` combined with `while True` as below:

```
$ cat x.py
#!/usr/bin/python

def replace(a,b): 
   while True:
      c = raw_input("Enter a letter you would like to replace:")
      if len(c) != 1 or c not in a:
         print "Invalid input! Try again"
      else:
         break

   d = ""    
   for char in a:
    if char == c:
        d += b        
    else:
        d+= char        
   print(d)


>>> from x import replace
>>> replace('this is a test', 'z')
Enter a letter you would like to replace:1
Invalid input! Try again
Enter a letter you would like to replace:q
Invalid input! Try again
Enter a letter you would like to replace:t
zhis is a zesz
```

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't exist in python 3, the author's using `input`.